# Find and Replace Value with id from one Array with another nested Array Object in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, nested-object

I have an first array like this

```
[
  ["Maths", "Chemistry", "Physics"],
  ["CS", "EC"],
  ["High", "Medium", "Low", "Average", "Excellent"]
]
```

And I have an another array of object in the below format

```
[
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Maths",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Chemistry",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Physics",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Social Science",
      is_active: 1
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: 10,
      name: "CS",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: "EC",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: "PHY",
      is_active: 1
    },
  ],
  [{
      id: 101,
      name: "High",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      name: "Low",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 103,
      name: "Medium",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 104,
      name: "Excellent",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 105,
      name: "Average",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 106,
      name: "Below Average",
      is_active: 1
    },
  ]
]
```

I need to replace the first array values with id by matching the names present in first array with name present in  the nested array of objects in second array.
My Final Output need to be in this format

```
[
    [1,2,3],
    [10,11],
    [101,103,102,105,104]
]
```

Can Anyone help me how to do this in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using map() and find() this :

- **simpleData** is your table containing only the names
- **fullData** is your table containing your objects

```js
let fullData = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Maths",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Chemistry",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Physics",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Social Science",
      is_active: 1
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: 10,
      name: "CS",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: "EC",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: "PHY",
      is_active: 1
    },
  ],
  [{
      id: 101,
      name: "High",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 102,
      name: "Low",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 103,
      name: "Medium",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 104,
      name: "Excellent",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 105,
      name: "Average",
      is_active: 1
    },
    {
      id: 106,
      name: "Below Average",
      is_active: 1
    },
  ]
]

let simpleData = [
  ["Maths", "Chemistry", "Physics"],
  ["CS", "EC"],
  ["High", "Medium", "Low", "Average", "Excellent"]
]

let newIdTable = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < fullData.length; i++ ) {
    let table = simpleData[i].map( ( name ) => {
        return fullData[i].find( item => item.name === name ).id
    } );

    newIdTable.push( table );
}

console.log(newIdTable)
```

Using **find()**, if the corresponding object doesn't exist it will return *undefined*. I didn't test the case here, because I supposed that your object already exist in the fullData table. So you have to modify the code with a condition to handle that case if you need :)